# Graphics draw image rendering weird squares

Tags: java, awt, 2d

So im making my own game in Java, yeah a weird thing. The problem is that ive made a method to return a BufferedImage with an image loaded in it:

```
    public static BufferedImage getImage(String img) {
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(Game.class.getResourceAsStream("./img/" + img));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    image.flush();
    return image;

}
```

This method is returning the image for my icon with no problems.

```
        frame.setIconImage(Game.getImage("icon.png"));
```

The problems is when i draw the image on the canvas:

```
            g.drawImage(Game.getImage("aa.png"), 0, 0,Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT,null);
```

That displays this:
[image: Error]

And the actual image is:
[image]

Can someone help me out?

I should say it works on Windows but not on GNU/Linux

Comment: Probably don't want to call `flush`, from the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#flush--) `"Flushes all reconstructable resources being used by this Image object. This includes any pixel data that is being cached for rendering to the screen as well as any system resources that are being used to store data or pixels for the image if they can be recreated"`

Comment: It wasnt the flush method still doesnt work.

Comment: Also the `getImage` method seems to be caching a reference to the image in an instance field - you shouldn't do this, you should just return the resulting image - and probably throw the exception, as it's not really the responsibility for the method to handle

Comment: Fixed that also and i still have the same error. I really dont know what to do with this, should be said it works on Windows but not on Linux OpenGL

Answer (score 0):

Taking your image, and placing in a subdirectory/package below this class (in the `img` package) worked just fine for me

[image: Layout]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new MenuPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class Game {
        public static BufferedImage getImage(String named) throws IOException {
            return ImageIO.read(Game.class.getResource("img/" + named));
        }
    }

    public class MenuPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage background;

        public MenuPane() {
            try {
                background = Game.getImage("aa.jpg");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return background == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
        }

    }

}
```

What did I notice?  `aa` is a `jpg` when I download, but is named as a `png` in your code, might not be an issue, but is a different.

Without a [Runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's near impossible to know what else to suggest

Comment: https://github.com/jaume5900/XAYB You can check the source code there, its a bit messy

Comment: It runs fine on MacOS

Comment: So... the problem is with linux... I dont know if its my distro ill try in a VM later and i update if it works.

Comment: Actually - it might have to do with how your managing the BufferStrategy

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that it was a hardware issue. I returned home and tested it on a VM + on the same HDD. It works just fine, sorry for taking your time to answer.